# Deleting from multiple tables in mysql

Tags: php, mysql, sql-delete

I'd like to combine the following two queries. Records will always exist in the users table and the active_kpi table, but they may not exist in the recipients table. Even if records are not in the recipients table, I still want the query to delete records from the other two tables.

```
    $sql = "DELETE u, ak FROM users u JOIN active_kpi ak ON ak.group_id = 
    u.group_id WHERE u.group_id = ?";
    $stmt = $this->db->prepare($sql);
    $stmt->execute([$group_id]);

    $sql = "DELETE FROM recipients WHERE group_id = ?";
    $stmt = $this->db->prepare($sql);
    $stmt->execute([$group_id]);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this:

```
DELETE u,ak,r
FROM users u INNER JOIN active_kpi ak ON ak.group_id = u.group_id 
    LEFT JOIN recipients r ON ak.group_id = r.group_id
WHERE u.group_id = ?
```

note that `left join` is used to covering rows with lack of recipients.